# Ubuntu server HDMI hot-pluggable on a RPi3b?

Tags: server, hdmi, raspberrypi

Hot plugging of HDMI seems to work well on Raspberry Pi OS (see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107047/94956)). I tried to achieve the same with Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my RPi3B+ by adding the same lines to `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
```

... but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to achieve hot HDMI switching on Ubuntu Server 20.04 for RPi series?